# Cypress + headless Electron: CoreText warning

Tags: electron, cypress, headless-browser

I have recently migrated to **macOS version Catalina**, test running using **Cypress version 7.4.0**, and browser **Electron v13.0.1** installed.

If a headless test runner using browser Electron is started as follows in the command line, the tests do run properly but the Cypress Helper initiates with the following warning:

```
cypress run --browser electron --headless

Cypress Helper (Renderer)[28020:1581833] CoreText note:  
    Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
Cypress Helper (Renderer)[28020:1581833] CoreText note: 
    Client requested name ".AppleSymbolsFB", it will get  
    Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI  
    font access should be through proper APIs such as  
    CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

This warning is not generated if a headless browser is Chrome.

```
cypress run --browser chrome --headless
```

Suggestions for resolving this warning issue?

Comment: I started getting this error in Cypress (CoreText) after recently upgrading my Mac's OS. So I  am guessing that it could be to do with this issue; https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/1088. MacOS contains updates to certain fonts, however they aren't being picked up by Electron yet.